# Close the active window by their name from the view model in c#?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

If more than one window is open at a time, how to close particular window from the view model?

Or

How to get all active windows and close the particular window from.view model in c#?

Comment: Assuming we're talking about windows of your own app, you have a record of the windows you created, haven't you? So just look there and close it. Or are we talking of arbitrary windows of other apps?

Answer (score 1):

You can get all open windows like:

```
foreach (var Window in App.Current.Windows)
  if (Window.GetType().Name.Equals("Recorder"))
      ((Window)Window).Close();
```

Comment: In foreach loop what is App?

Comment: @SarthakAgarwal that’s a build in variable represents your current application

Comment: After using the above code, I am not able to open this recorder window again. What is way to open it again?

Answer (score -2):

Yes, we are talking about the windows of my application. At a time if more than
one window active and I want to close the window whose name is (x: name="Recorder").

Comment: For any update regarding the question, edit the question and update it.

Comment: Above solution is working fine. Thanks all for the response.